# How to make an application perform an action whenever a shake is detected?

Tags: objective-c

I want to know the way to display images whenever the iPhone detects a shake.The images would be those stored in a folder in the iPhone. A source code would really be helpful.

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)motionBegan:(UIEventSubtype)motion withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
      if (event.subtype == UIEventSubtypeMotionShake) {
                // The user shook the device
      }
}
```